# Python array sorting

Tags: python, arrays

I want to sort a list so that I can feed in an attribute of the list into a loop. Let me elaborate :

Let's say I have:

```
data = [('turtle', 'sock'), ('frog', 'hat'), ('turtle', 'shirt'), ('frog', 'boot')]
```

and I only want the tuples that are related to the `'turtle'`, so I want:

```
newdata = [('turtle', 'sock'), ('turtle', 'shirt')]
```

Then I want to put `'sock'` and `'shirt'` in a list so that I can do something like:

```
lst = ['sock', 'shirt']
```

Then I can do something like

```
print "what is the turtle wearing?" 
for item in lst:
    print "the turtle is wearing a " + item
```

My idea was to sort the array so that all things related to the turtle could be put into a separate list. Then split that, but my knowledge of list is minimal. So any help or forwarding to helpful links is greatly appreciated. I hope this is a nice basic example to express my needs.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a dict -> list mapping?

Comment: I will be presented with data in an array. If using your suggestion is easier I would love to hear how to use that instead.

Comment: `sorted(list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), filter(lambda x: x[0] == 'turtle', data))))`. Oh yeah, don't forget to import operator

Comment: ... but it is better to process the list once and generate a dict `item -> wearing` dict as @FatalError suggested.

Comment: Okay I looked them up some, I think that may work well! do you know of a good place for examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably most appropriate to build a `dict` that holds what each animal wears (as I mentioned in the comment):

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [('turtle', 'sock'), ('frog', 'hat'), ('turtle', 'shirt'), ('frog', 'boot')]

d = defaultdict(list)
for animal, clothing in data:
    d[animal].append(clothing)

print d['turtle']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [('turtle', 'sock'), ('frog', 'hat'), ('turtle', 'shirt'), ('frog', 'boot')]

def function(key):
    listWithKey = []
    for element in data:
        if element[0] == key:
            listWithKey.append(element[1])
    return listWithKey

print(function("turtle"))
```

This is a more basic approach just using lists and loops. The output is `['sock', 'shirt']`

Comment: This approach could be written more simply using list comprehensions. `[x[1] for x in data if x[0] == 'turtle']`