# How to structure multiple python arrays for sorting

Tags: arrays, sorting, numpy

A fourier analysis I'm doing outputs 5 data fields, each of which I've collected into 1-d numpy arrays: freq bin #, amplitude, wavelength, normalized amplitude, %power.

**How best to structure the data so I can sort by descending amplitude?**

When testing with just one data field, I was able to use a dict as follows:

```
fourier_tuples = zip(range(len(fourier)), fourier)
fourier_map = dict(fourier_tuples)
import operator
fourier_sorted = sorted(fourier_map.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
fourier_sorted = np.argsort(-fourier)[:3]
```

My intent was to add the other arrays to line 1, but this doesn't work since dicts only accept 2 terms. (That's why [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086373/python-array-sorting) doesn't solve my issue.)

Stepping back, is this a reasonable approach, or are there better ways to combine & sort separate arrays? Ultimately, I want to take the data values from the top 3 freqs and associated other data, and write them to an output data file.

Here's a snippet of my data:

```
fourier = np.array([1.77635684e-14, 4.49872050e+01, 1.05094837e+01, 8.24322470e+00, 2.36715913e+01])
freqs = np.array([0.        ,  0.00246951,  0.00493902,  0.00740854,  0.00987805])
wavelengths = np.array([inf, 404.93827165, 202.46913583, 134.97942388, 101.23456791])
amps = np.array([4.33257766e-16, 1.09724890e+00, 2.56328871e-01, 2.01054261e-01, 5.77355886e-01])
powers% = np.array([4.8508237956526163e-32, 0.31112370227749603, 0.016979224022185751, 0.010445983875848858, 0.086141014686372669])
```

The last 4 arrays are other fields corresponding to 'fourier'. (Actual array lengths are 42, but pared down to 5 for simplicity.)

Comment: Could you add some data?!

Comment: Arrays? Do you mean *lists*? Why are you using a `dict`, then simply calling `items`? That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: is `zip(range(len(fourier)), fourier)` short for `enumerate(fourier)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I failed to mention I'm working in numpy; yes, these are arrays, not lists.
I'm trying to modify an approach I saw elsewhere to suit my needs. It appeared to work as hoped, until I started working with more than a single array. I'm calling items as my iterable b/c sorting doesn't work on a dict.
I'm new, and I'm *certain* there's a better way. I'm all ears.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: Yes, they appear to contain the same information. I haven't used enumerate(), but it seems I can't print results to the console, as I can the 'fourier_tuples' array I created.

Comment: @Cleb: Added some data

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using numpy, so here is the numpy way of doing this. You have the right function `np.argsort` in your post, but you don't seem to use it correctly:

```
order = np.argsort(amplitudes)
```

This is similar to your dictionary trick only it computes the inverse shuffling compared to your procedure. Btw. why go through a dictionary and not simply a list of tuples?

The contents of `order` are now indices into `amplitudes` the first cell of `order` contains the position of the smallest element of `amplitudes`, the second cell contains the position of the next etc. Therefore

```
top5 = order[:-6:-1]
```

Provided your data are 1d numpy `array`s you can use `top5` to extract the elements corresponding to the top 5 ampltiudes by using *advanced indexing*

```
freq_bin[top5]
amplitudes[top5]
wavelength[top5]
```

If you want you can group them together in columns and apply `top5` to the resulting n-by-5 array:

```
np.c_[freq_bin, amplitudes, wavelength, ...][top5, :]
```

Comment: I'm new to numpy, and was simply mimicking an approach I'd seen elsewhere. I'm not surprised it's not the best way. If tuples are more sensible, so much the better. I created tuples like so: 
`fourier_tuples = zip(range(len(fourier)), freqs, wavelengths, fourier, amps, powers)`. Then created 'top5' as above and ran `fourier_tuples[top5]`.
RESULT: "TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index"

Comment: @joechoj I meant tuples if you want to work along the lines of your original attempt. When you call `.items()` the key-value pairs of your dictionary are converted to tuples,  but that way you can group only 2, with a list of tuples you can group all. -- As I state in the answer, if you want to use my approach you must use numpy arrays because they understand advanced indexing, tuples don't. The equivalent of zip in numpy terms is the `np.c_[...]` in the last line

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have 5 separate lists of the same length and you are trying to sort all of them based on one of them. To do that you can either use numpy or do it with vanilla python. Here are two examples from top of my head (sorting is based on the 2nd list).

```
a = [11,13,10,14,15]
b = [2,4,1,0,3]
c = [22,20,23,25,24]

#numpy solution
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([a,b,c])
my_sorted_array = my_array[:,my_array[1,:].argsort()]

#vanilla python solution
from operator import itemgetter

my_list = zip(a,b,c)
my_sorted_list = sorted(my_list,key=itemgetter(1))
```

You can then flip the array with `my_sorted_array = np.fliplr(my_sorted_array)` if you wish or if you are working with lists you can reverse it in place with `my_sorted_list.reverse()`

**EDIT:**

To get first n values only, you have to simply [slice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) the array similarly to what [@Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7207392/paul-panzer) is suggesting. Slice is done in a similar manner to classic list slicing by specifying `start:stop:step` (you can omit the step) arguments. In your case for 5 top columns it would be `[:,-5:]`. So in the example above you can take top 2 columns from each row like this:

```
my_sliced_sorted_array = my_sorted_array[:,-2:]
```

result will be:

```
array([[15, 13],
       [ 3,  4],
       [24, 20]])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I like the numpy solution, but can't quite make it work. I created a 'my_flipped_array' as you suggested. Can the array be truncated to include just the top x values? Though maybe I don't need to do that, as results are all accessible via indexing...

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'd been trying 'my_flipped_array[:][:3]', which ended up returning the entire dataset, somehow. Any idea why this doesn't work? By contrast, 'my_flipped_array[0][:3]' does return the first 3 values from the first array.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, can you please explain? This seems like a fine approach to me... Is there some reason I'd run into problems using this? Is the answer by @Paul Panzer preferable somehow?