# Why doesn't a negative array work to reverse numpy.argsort()?

Tags: arrays, sorting, numpy, reverse

I have a 2D numpy array called 'subset':

```
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   2.46951219e-03,   4.93902439e-03],
       [             inf,   4.04938272e+02,   2.02469136e+02],
       [  1.77635684e-14,   4.49872050e+01,   1.05094837e+01],
       [  4.33257766e-16,   1.09724890e+00,   2.56328871e-01],
       [  4.85082380e-32,   3.11123702e-01,   1.69792239e-02]])
```

I'm trying to sort by array 2 (3rd array) in *descending* order. The following works for *ascending* order:

```
>>> subset[:,subset[2,:].argsort()]
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   4.93902439e-03,   2.46951219e-03],
       [             inf,   2.02469136e+02,   4.04938272e+02],
       [  1.77635684e-14,   1.05094837e+01,   4.49872050e+01],
       [  4.33257766e-16,   2.56328871e-01,   1.09724890e+00],
       [  4.85082380e-32,   1.69792239e-02,   3.11123702e-01]])
```

As you can see, the 3rd array is sorted by increasing order, and the other rows get sorted the same way, preserving the columns as intended.

But when I try to reverse this sorting by doing the same operation on the negative array (thinking it should produce the mirror image of the prior result), it doesn't work as intended.

```
>>> subset[:,-subset[2,:].argsort()]
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   2.46951219e-03,   4.93902439e-03],
       [             inf,   4.04938272e+02,   2.02469136e+02],
       [  1.77635684e-14,   4.49872050e+01,   1.05094837e+01],
       [  4.33257766e-16,   1.09724890e+00,   2.56328871e-01],
       [  4.85082380e-32,   3.11123702e-01,   1.69792239e-02]])
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: operator precedence?

Comment: `-subset[2,:].argsort()` means `-(subset[2,:].argsort())` not `(-subset[2,:]).argsort()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is, of course, operator precedence. A pair of parentheses and it does what you want:

```
subset[:,(-subset[2,:]).argsort()]
# array([[  2.46951219e-03,   4.93902439e-03,   0.00000000e+00],
#        [  4.04938272e+02,   2.02469136e+02,              inf],
#        [  4.49872050e+01,   1.05094837e+01,   1.77635684e-14],
#        [  1.09724890e+00,   2.56328871e-01,   4.33257766e-16],
#        [  3.11123702e-01,   1.69792239e-02,   4.85082380e-32]])
```

But note that simple reversal is typically faster:

```
timeit(lambda: subset[:,(-subset[2,:]).argsort()])
# 2.9420917620009277
timeit(lambda: subset[:,subset[2,:].argsort()[::-1]])
# 2.556215071992483
```

Comment: That's great - thanks for the explanation & tip. I'll go with that [::-1] method.

Comment: Hey, can I ask you to look back at my related question to which you provided an answer? I'm trying to figure out which method is preferable, yours or kyjanond's. Any insight to why one works better than the other? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42380283/how-to-structure-multiple-python-arrays-for-sorting/42380661#42380661?

Comment: @joechoj You mean of the answers given there? I would certainly go with one of the numpy solutions. The main differences between my and the other solution are. Mine puts your lists in columns the other one in rows. In mine the top amplitude comes first, in the other solution it comes last. Apart from that they are more or less identical, I'd say.